# Loop through Access tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, loops

I'm creating a database in Access that will have many similar tables with identical and the names of them will all be named in sequential order, such as table_0, table_1...

I wanted to know if there is a way to make a loop in VBA to first make the tables, and them altering them, such as adding a field easier.

So if I were to make the tables, this would be the process, but in VBA

```
while(i=0, i<20,i++){
CREATE TABLE  table_i(
field_1 int PRIMARY KEY,
field_2 CHAR(255));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, you can loop through your numbered table names like this ...

```
Dim strTable As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 20
    strTable = "table_" & CStr(i)
    Debug.Print strTable
Next i
```

But you want to do something with each table name other than print it.  So say you've already worked out your `CREATE TABLE` statement.  Maybe it looks like this ...

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
field_1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
field_2 TEXT(255));
```

So you could load that DDL statement into a string variable, then each time through your `For` loop replace `table_name` with the current value of `strTable`, and execute that DDL statement.

```
Dim strTable As String
Dim i As Long
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "CREATE TABLE table_name (" & vbCrLf & _
    "field_1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," & vbCrLf & _
    "field_2 TEXT(255));"
For i = 0 To 20
    strTable = "table_" & CStr(i)
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute Replace(strSql, _
        "table_name", strTable)
Next i
```

That `Replace()` function first became available with Access 2000.  If you're using an older Access version, you'll need a different method to handle your SQL string.

If you want to execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement, you could do that instead.

So I think doing what you want can be easily done with VBA.  However I'm uncertain whether you *should* do it.  Multiple tables with identical structure is generally a red flag signalling a design error.  There is no evidence to conclude it's a design error in your case.  OTOH, there is no evidence to conclude it's *not* a design error.  ;-)

Comment: +1. I'd add an extra upvote just for adding the last paragraph if I could. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite That last paragraph was my real motivation to submit this answer.  :-)  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, :-) And as for the last paragraph, I'm not sure if I have the right structure, but I wasn't sure if this was the right place to ask about that. I'm organizing identical tables from excel that have the same fields and rows into access. I could throw all the data into one table, but the I would just have one big spreadsheet

Comment: You replied before I finished my edit, that's where I asked. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Here is where I asked:    http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20757/table-structure-for-keeping-track-of-multiple-similar-accounts